# How to return and render a SVG image via AWS lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'd like to have a lambda function build an SVG image and then return the image when an API is hit.

My question is how do you return the image so that if a user goes to "mywebsite.com/image/1" it doesn't return the text of the SVG but instead loads the image as if they directly went to an image?

Would you return HTML that includes an `<img/>` with the src being the SVG?

Or would you base64 encode the SVG and return it with the proper content type?

Also - it needs to be able to be read via servers as well - so other pages can hit the API and be able to save the image.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that you need to return the content type.  There's no need to base64 encode it, since it's not binary data, generally.

This simple example shows how to return set content type for an SVG graphic.  When viewed with an API Gateway, browsers will render the SVG image.  Any client can still download the SVG data by calling the same endpoint, of course.

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // Just show a star as an example
    const exampleSvg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">' + 
         '<path d="M50,3l12,36h38l-30,22l11,36l-31-21l-31,21l11-36l-30-22h38z" ' + 
         'fill="#FF0" stroke="#FC0" stroke-width="2"/>' + 
         '</svg>';

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: exampleSvg,
        headers: {
            // Set the content type to the correct Mime type
            'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml',
        },
    };
    return response;
};
```